# Twitter search with Jquery and ajax

Tags: ajax, json

Currently my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <title>Search Tweets</title>
<style type = "text/css">

#tweets{
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}
#box{
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
#btn{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#main{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}




</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var params = {
            q: $('#query').val(),
            rpp: 10
        };
        searchTwitter(params);
    });

function searchTwitter(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?' + jQuery.param(query),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            var tweets = $('#tweets');
            tweets.html('');
            for (res in data['results']) {
                tweets.append('<div>' + data['results'][res]['profile_image_url'] + data['results'][res]['from_user'] + ' Said: <p>' + data['results'][res]['text'] + '</p></div><br />');

            }
        }
    });
    }
});


</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id ="main">
    <div id ="box">
        <input id="query" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div id ="btn">
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Search" />
    </div>

</div>
    <div id="tweets">Tweets

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Everything is working properly however when it recieves the code from the profile image url it only displays the URL and not the image itself.  How do i get the profile image to get displayed instead of just the code?

Thank you

Comment: This is going to stop working any time now. This is part of Twitter's API v1.0 and it is deprecated. They are shutting it down piece by piece. You need to switch over to API 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the image url in an img tag

```
tweets.append('<div><img src="' + data['results'][res]['profile_image_url'] +'">' + data['results'][res]['from_user'] + ' Said: <p>' + data['results'][res]['text'] + '</p></div><br />');
```

Comment: Wow i cant believe I overlooked that.  Thank you so much!